# SQL - How to check if the dates are continuous for a single record

Tags: sql, postgresql, logic

I have below data in postgres for which I need to write a query which satisfies all 3 cases mentioned below:

Brief of all 3 cases:

For same id, if there is no gap in dates between end date and next start date (i.e., continuous), then we can club them into one record and display the active ones.
For same id, if there is a gap between end date and next start date, and if the end record falls under 12 months, then we should display both records with respective dates.
For same id, if there is a gap between dates and if the end record doesn't fall under 12 months, then we should not send the record. only active can be sent.

**Case 1 (continuous active within timeframe):**
id   start_date  end_date    status
1    1/1/2018    31/1/2018   Inactive
1    1/2/2018    31/12/2021  Inactive
1    1/1/2022    1/1/2300    Active
[continuous active records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJkgS.png)

**Expected Output:**

id   start_date  end_date    status
1    1/1/2018    1/1/2300    Active

**Case 2  (Gap and inactive under 12 months):**

id   start_date  end_date    status
2    1/1/2021    31/12/2021  Inactive
2    1/7/2022    1/1/2300    Active

**Expected Output:**

id   start_date  end_date    status
2    1/1/2021    31/12/2021  Inactive
2    1/7/2022    1/1/2300    Active

**Case 3 (Gap and inactive above 12 months):**

id   start_date  end_date    status
3    1/1/2020    31/12/2020  Inactive
3    1/7/2022    1/1/2300    Active

**Expected Output:**
id   start_date  end_date    status
3    1/7/2022    1/1/2300    Active

I have written a query to combine records and display it as one single record. But, I have no idea how to check if the dates are continuous. Anyone could please help me in giving some idea on this.

Comment: Not seeing how came up with `id start_date end_date status 1 1/1/2018 1/1/2300 Active` as there is an inactive periods in there from `1/1/2018` to  `31/1/2018` and `1/2/2018` to `31/12/2021`  and you said you only want continuous active periods. Also see [Table Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) for how to format your tables.

Comment: Yeah, that means that id was active from 1/1/2018 to 31/1/2018 and then it got expired and status got inactive as it got termed out. and a new one started where he was active again from the next day onwards i.e., 1/2/2018 to 31/12/2021 and then it got expired and then started a new one from next day. so, he was active in continuous time period without any gaps in dates. so, we need to get output as single record which contains the start date as the minimum start date (i.e., when he actually started being active) and end date is latest active records one (ie., max end date)